# PHP - Query inside query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple query but I need to make another query inside it. I have very little knowledge of SQL and PHP so I want to ask your help.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM img");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $imgName = $row['name'];
   $catID = $row['catid'];
   // Problem
   // Need to get category NAME from category ID
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM cat WHERE id = $catID");
   while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
   {
      $catName = $row2['name'];
   }

   echo "Image: $imgName <br />";
   echo "Category: $catName";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be a simple `JOIN` to get the category name.  You can use a single query:

```
SELECT
  img.id AS imgId,
  img.name AS imgName,
  cat.name AS catName
FROM img JOIN cat ON img.catid = cat.id
```

Replace your initial query with the above, and it will eliminate the need for the inner query.

Comment: @Qmal See edit above -- Be more explicit than `img.*` then.  Reference image id as `imgId`, image name as `imgName`, and category name  as `catName` in `$row[]`

Comment: Yea I got it that's why deleted the comment :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You'll see all the img properties of each table in each row and in addition the cat.name value.

```
SELECT *, cat.name as catname FROM img
INNER JOIN cat
ON cat.id = img.catid
```

Comment: You're missing selecting cat.name at your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple subquery on this one:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT name, catid, (SELECT name FROM cat WHERE id = img.catid) AS cat_name
FROM img
");
```

Comment: Uh, not sure about that. If there are many rows in the table that could be quite slow. Doing an inner join seems like the much better solution.